# How do I convert a byte array to Base64 in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Okay, I know how to do it in C#.

It's as simple as:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])
and Convert.FromBase64String(string) to get byte[] back.
```

How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 374):

## Java 8+

Encode or decode byte arrays:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode("Hello".getBytes());
println(new String(encoded));   // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
println(new String(decoded))    // Outputs "Hello"
```

Or if you just want the strings:

```
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("Hello".getBytes());
println(encoded);   // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

String decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded.getBytes()));
println(decoded)    // Outputs "Hello"
```

For more info, see [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

## Java < 8

Base64 is not bundled with Java versions less than 8. I recommend using [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/index.html).

For direct byte arrays:

```
Base64 codec = new Base64();
byte[] encoded = codec.encode("Hello".getBytes());
println(new String(encoded));   // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

byte[] decoded = codec.decode(encoded);
println(new String(decoded))    // Outputs "Hello"
```

Or if you just want the strings:

```
Base64 codec = new Base64();
String encoded = codec.encodeBase64String("Hello".getBytes());
println(encoded);   // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

String decoded = new String(codec.decodeBase64(encoded));
println(decoded)    // Outputs "Hello"
```

## Spring

If you're working in a Spring project already, you may find their [`org.springframework.util.Base64Utils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Base64Utils.html) class more ergonomic:

For direct byte arrays:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64Utils.encode("Hello".getBytes());
println(new String(encoded))    // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

byte[] decoded = Base64Utils.decode(encoded);
println(new String(decoded))    // Outputs "Hello"
```

Or if you just want the strings:

```
String encoded = Base64Utils.encodeToString("Hello".getBytes());
println(encoded);   // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

String decoded = Base64Utils.decodeFromString(encoded);
println(new String(decoded))    // Outputs "Hello"
```

## Android (with Java < 8)

If you are using the Android SDK before Java 8 then your best option is to use the bundled `android.util.Base64`.

For direct byte arrays:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.encode("Hello".getBytes());
println(new String(encoded))    // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

byte [] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded);
println(new String(decoded))    // Outputs "Hello"
```

Or if you just want the strings:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString("Hello".getBytes());
println(encoded);   // Outputs "SGVsbG8="

String decoded = new String(Base64.decode(encoded));
println(decoded)    // Outputs "Hello"
```

Comment: On Android, the `encode` and `encodeToString` methods also expect a `flags` parameter, so you need to do `Base64.encode("Hello".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);` (and the same for `encodeToString`).

Comment: great answer, in my opinion must be accepted as correct answer.

Answer (score 35):

Use:

```
byte[] data = Base64.encode(base64str);
```

Encoding converts to Base64

You would need to reference [commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) from your project in order for that code to work.

**For java8**:

```
import java.util.Base64
```

Comment: The methods for encode / decode of class Base64 are static so you don't need to create a new object. Then: byte [] data = Base64.decode(base64str); is enough.

Answer (score 22):

Additionally, for our Android friends (API Level 8):

```
import android.util.Base64

...

Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 8):

In case you happen to be using Spring framework along with java, there is an easy way around.

1. Import the following.

   ```
   import org.springframework.util.Base64Utils;
   ```
2. Convert like this.

   ```
   byte[] bytearr ={0,1,2,3,4};
   String encodedText = Base64Utils.encodeToString(bytearr);
   ```

   To decode you can use the decodeToString method of the Base64Utils class.