# How to create byte array out of bytes

Tags: java

I get a PDF image as Base64Encoded bytes in an XML file, something like this(much longer, stripped):

> JVBERi0xLjMKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovUGFnZXMgMyAwIFIKL091dGxpbmVzIDIgMCBSCi9EZXN0cyA1IDAgUgovUGFnZU1vZGUgL1VzZU5vbm

Want to write java code to convert it into image file . I tried using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byte[])` but not sure how to create `byte[]` of above bytes.

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418485/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-base64-in-java

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: I went though this link already but doesn't tell me how can I store my encoded image in a byte[]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the sun.misc.BASE64Decoder

```
public byte[] fromBase64(String b64) {
  BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
  return decoder.decodeBuffer(b64)
}
```

Comment: my question is how do I pass bytes to methods. In this example, string is required to pass. In my original question, I used a method which takes byte[] but I don't know how to create byte[] out of my bytes

Comment: Do not use the package `sun.misc`. It's not part of Java SE and may change in future versions of Java.

Comment: @Learner. The above method takes in your string and creates a byte array, byte[]. That's how you get the bytes represented by your base-64-encoded string.

Comment: @MarlonBernandes Agree. Actually, JDK 8 finally brings Base64 encoder/decoder as a part of standard "tools".