# correct way of extracting image (BLOB) from ORACLE

Tags: java, oracle, blob

I have a project in which i need to extract some images in BLOB format as string, from an ORACLE database to send it through a JSON. I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE.

Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

Would this be the proper way to extract the BLOB data as string?

```
        String query = "SELECT operation, c_book, x_book, x_text1, x_text2, x_text3, x_text4,"
                           + "UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(img_logo,32670,1))FROM "
                           + dataBaseConnectionData.getDB_SHCHEMA() + "."+ dataBaseConnectionData.getDB_TABLE_COLA()
                           + " WHERE status = 'P' OR status = 'N' OR status = 'E'" 
                           + " ORDER BY c_book";
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to get BLOB data using JDBC:

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("img_logo")
InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream("img_logo")
byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes("img_logo")
```

If the blob is of limited size, which a logo would be, the third version is the easiest to use.

You will then need to convert to a string, which means you need to know which encoding was used to convert the original text to binary in the first place. The most conservative choice would be `US-ASCII`, so:

```
String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)
```

Of course, this assumes the binary data is text, but it's a logo, and that doesn't sound like a text value, so you might have meant that you want to encode the binary data for embedding in a JSON structure, to be decoded back to binary at the other end.

For that, you'd need to decide on an encoding. The two top choices are HEX and BASE64, where HEX will double the size (two hex digits per byte), and BASE64 will add 33% (4 chars per 3 bytes).

For HEX, see [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)
For BASE64, see [How do I convert a byte array to Base64 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418485/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-base64-in-java), or use the new [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class (Java 8).