# Rebuild byte array with bigInteger and other method

Tags: java, encoding, arrays, biginteger

when I doing the signature encoding I meet a stranger problem:

When I want to rebuild a byte array, it always failed with :

```
//digest is the original byte array
        String messageHex = bytesToHex(digest);
        byte[] hexRestore = messageHex.getBytes();
        assert Arrays.equals(digest, hexRestore);   //false!    

        String utf8Digest = new String(digest, "UTF8");
        byte[] utf8Restore = utf8Digest.getBytes("UTF8");
        assert Arrays.equals(digest, utf8Restore);    //false!
```

Then I use big Integer:

```
        BigInteger messageBig = new BigInteger(digest);
        byte[] bigRestore = messageBig.toByteArray();
        assert Arrays.equals(digest, bigRestore));    //true!
```

Then it works, I don't know why, c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use either of these approaches. Either convert into hex directly (not using `BigInteger`) or use base64. `BigInteger` will faithfully reproduce *numbers*, but it's not meant to be a general purpose binary-to-hex converter. In particular, it will lose leading zeroes, because they're insignificant when treating the data *as an integer*. (If you know the expected length you could always format it to that, but why bother? Just treat the data as arbitrary data instead of as a number.)

*Definitely* don't try to "decode" the byte array as if it's UTF-8-encoded text - it isn't.

There are plenty of questions on Stack Overflow about converting byte arrays to [hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) or [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418485). (Those are just links to two examples... search for more.)

Comment: I tried the hex method from your post as well, but it doesn't work either, and I also wondering why... I also add the code into the question

Comment: @Haven: You're calling `String.getBytes`. That's *not* how you convert hex back to a byte array. You're getting the representation of that text in the default encoding...