# Spring MVC image and text to be rendered

Tags: spring-mvc

I dont want to use view but I would like to render text and image on webpage, any suggestion?
tried like returning String with the img tag src=bytearray but it doesnt render image (other text are rendered ok)
any suggession please?

**Controller goes like this**

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
String generateTextMessage(@RequestParam("id") final String guid, @RequestParam("key") final String pID);
```

**String being returned from contorller**

```
info="data to be displayed on browser"+ name
info=info+ "+ " Photo: <IMG SRC=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+photo.getimPhoto().toByteArray() +"\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\" alt=\"testpic\" >";
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560229/convert-byte-to-image-and-display-on-jsp

Comment: Thanks this helped

Comment: You are welcome :)