# Convert ByteArray to Base64 in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, base64

I am trying to convert a ByteArray to Base64 in a Spring project, written in Kotlin. I have checked existing posts but they didnt help me. Actually I am trying to convert a blob to base, but I converted the blob to byteArray so far and am struggling now to convert the bytearray to base64. This is what I am currently trying:

```
var inByteArray = Base64.encodeBase64(blobAsBytes)         //inByteArray : ByteArray!
var inByteArrayFormatted = Base64Utils.decode(inByteArray) //inByteArrayFormatted : ByteArray
```

I tried the things from this post [How do I convert a byte array to Base64 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418485/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-base64-in-java), but they are just encoding strings but not directly to Base64. How can I convert a byte array to Base64? Not encoded strings but Base64?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: And what is `Base64` in your understanding? Because that answer is exactly what you need, but I think you are misunderstanding something. And in your code you are converting to base64 and then converting back, kind of a no-op.

Comment: Yeah Base64 is a string representation of binary data, it uses 64 characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and two more)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using Kotlin with Java, you can use `java.util.Base64` to encode a `ByteArray` into a `String`. I wrote an extension function to do this:

```
fun ByteArray.toBase64(): String = 
    String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(this))

// Use:
val b64 = "asdf".toByteArray().toBase64()
// YXNkZg==
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val encodedUrl = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(oriUrl.toByteArray())
```