# Parse a byte array into a ByteArray

Tags: kotlinx.serialization

from a server I get an array of bytes, but Kotlinx serializable doesen't seem to like it as it can't parse it to the native Kotlin datatype `ByteArray` and logs the error `Unexpected JSON token at offset 902: Failed to parse 'byte'`:

JSON = `"my_bytes": "[[22, 124, 78, etc...], [233, 89, 112, etc...], [etc...]]"` and I wanna serialize that into a `ByteArray` so I can then write a file with that `ByteArray` with the `File.writeBytes(my_byte_array)`

My code by the way:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class ServerResponse(
    val audio: List<ByteArray>
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? For example a main function `fun main() {}` that we can run.

Comment: I'm confused because the JSON you've posted isn't an array (it's wrapped in quotes, so it's a string), the property name doesn't match (`my_bytes` vs `audio`), and the JSON contains non-byte values (233 is too large for a byte, the max value is 127). Also, do you have control over how the value is serialized? If so, you might want to [base64 encode the bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64486317/4161471) as a string instead of sending them in an array.