# How to display a binary image stored in mongodb, in Html

Tags: java, angular, mongodb

The binary image data is stored in mongodb collection as shown below

```
image:Binary('XXXXXXXXXXX...', 0)
```

when I am trying to display it in html

```
<div > <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{person.image}}"/></div>
```

It gives me this error when executing:

> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME png;base64,[object Object]:1

I didn't convert the binary data to base64

Comment: [object Object] Looks a bit off.. what do you see when you just do {{person.image | json}} somewhere in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Binary](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/types/Binary.html) is class that has only the default `toString` method.

To get the data URL string you will probably need to use the Binary class `getData` method to return a byte array, and then convert that to a base64 string as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33552306/2282634

Comment: Problem solved yesterday, indeed i used Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(BinaryObject.getData())